# Find dominant eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Consider the $5x5$ tridiagonal matrix with entries $a_{i,i} = 2$,
> $i=1,2,...,5$ and $a_{i,i+1}= a_{i+1, i} = 1$ , $i=1,...,4$. Knowing
> that the initial approximation $x_0  =(0.5,0.8,1,0.8,0.5)$  is almost
> aligned with the dominant eigenvector of the matrix, determine until
> the fifth iteration an approximation of the dominant eigenvalue.

So, the first thing I did was to construct the matrix:
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ \end{bmatrix}$

Then I calculated $A^5x_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 348.2\\603.1\\696.4\\603.1\\348.2\end{bmatrix} = \lambda^5x_0$. But from now on I'm stuck. How can I calculate the dominant eigenvector from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_0$ is close to the dominant eigenspace. $A^4x_0$ is even closer to the dominant eigenspace. Choose an entry (say, the first entry), and calculate the ratio between that entry in $A^5x_0$ and $A^4x_0$.

Comment: That's the right answer indeed according to solutions. But could you please elaborate on why that is the case?

Comment: @rato Elaborate on why what is the case? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Because I don't really understand the logic behind the ratio of the component at 5th iteration with the same component on the 4th iteration being the dominant eigenvalue.

Comment: @rato Since $A^4x$ is almost an eigenvector corresponding to the dominant eigenvalue $\lambda$, we get $$A^5x=A(A^4x)\approx \lambda A^4x$$The easiest way to (approximately) find this $\lambda$ is just to see how much one entry is scaled by as you go from $A^4x$ to $A^5x$. If $A^4x$ were a true eigenvector, the entries would all scale by the same amount. Since it is instead close to a true eigenvector, the entries each scale a little differently, but they all scale close to the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

The question only asks you to compute the dominant *eigenvalue*, which is approximated by the fifth root of 696.4.